# FireBreath using external boost

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, firebreath

I'm trying to make FireBreath use of the alternative boost libraries I have on my machine.
I followed the [information in the site](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Prep+Scripts#PrepScripts-ExternalBoost) but to no avail.

Here's what I'm getting when I run the prep script:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:94 (add_boost_library)

project dir: C:/Workspace/MyPlugin
Single project: C:/Workspace/MyPlugin
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_filesystem

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/PluginConfig.cmake:74 (add_boost_library)
  cmake/common.cmake:73 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (add_firebreath_plugin)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_filesystem
          boost_date_time

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/PluginConfig.cmake:75 (add_boost_library)
  cmake/common.cmake:73 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (add_firebreath_plugin)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_filesystem
          boost_date_time
          boost_regex

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/PluginConfig.cmake:76 (add_boost_library)
  cmake/common.cmake:73 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (add_firebreath_plugin)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_filesystem
          boost_date_time
          boost_regex
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/PluginConfig.cmake:77 (add_boost_library)
  cmake/common.cmake:73 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (add_firebreath_plugin)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_filesystem
          boost_date_time
          boost_regex
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/PluginConfig.cmake:78 (add_boost_library)
  cmake/common.cmake:73 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:125 (add_firebreath_plugin)


Generating plugin configuration files in C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/build-2013/projects/MyPlugin/gen
Configuring C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/Win/WiX/MyPluginInstaller.wxs -> C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/build-2013/projects/MyPlugin/MyPluginInstaller.wxs
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  cmake/common.cmake:97 (add_boost_library)
  tests/ScriptingCoreTest/CMakeLists.txt:56 (link_boost_library)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_system
          boost_date_time

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  cmake/common.cmake:97 (add_boost_library)
  tests/ScriptingCoreTest/CMakeLists.txt:57 (link_boost_library)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_system
          boost_date_time
          boost_regex

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  cmake/common.cmake:97 (add_boost_library)
  tests/ScriptingCoreTest/CMakeLists.txt:58 (link_boost_library)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  cmake/common.cmake:97 (add_boost_library)
  tests/ActiveXCoreTest/CMakeLists.txt:82 (link_boost_library)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_system
          boost_date_time

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  cmake/common.cmake:97 (add_boost_library)
  tests/ActiveXCoreTest/CMakeLists.txt:83 (link_boost_library)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.56.0

  Boost include path: C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_chrono
          boost_system
          boost_date_time
          boost_regex

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/common.cmake:111 (find_package)
  cmake/common.cmake:97 (add_boost_library)
  tests/ActiveXCoreTest/CMakeLists.txt:84 (link_boost_library)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Workspace/MyPlugin/build-2013/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I had some trouble passing the parameters to the prep script, so I just modified the winprep.cmd script to:

```
cmake -G %_FB_GEN% -DWITH_SYSTEM_BOOST=1 -DBOOST_ROOT=C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0 -BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:/Workspace/boost/boost_1_56_0/bin.v2/lib %PDIR% %CMAKE_PARAMS% %FB_ROOT%
```

What am I doing wrong? I did set `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`, `BOOST_ROOT`, and `WITH_SYSTEM_BOOST` but still get all these errors, which also seem to be repeating itself..

I am using these boost libraries with other projects and so I know it's working fine.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not so much a firebreath issue as an issue with the cmake Boost integration; I don't use system boost, so I don't know what the issue is for sure, unless something has changed in 1.56 since the versions that have been tested with FireBreath and some of those libraries are gone

Comment: 1. Set BOOST_ROOT to where you boost located (where include and lib folders are), 2. make sure that libraries exists - this algorithm should be sufficient for all such problems.

Comment: @Sergey but I did set `BOOST_ROOT` and the libs indeed exist (as I used them in other projects)

Comment: Found out the problem, I was stupid and gave it the wrong `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` path, should be BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib

Comment: consider also to add `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` to see details

Comment: yeah, I found that helpful flag during my searches, it helped a bit.